# Notepad++ find and replace expression help

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I want to find all content between two characters, say `A` and `B`:

`Asd;lfksjd;fsdfjs;ldfkB` which would be `sd;lfksjd;fsdfjs;ldfk`

and replace them. How would I write this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match any character between A and B with the following RegEx:

```
(?<=A).*(?=B)
```

This doesn't return A or B as part of the matched characters.

- `(?<=A)` means that A comes before the main expression and that if it matches you don't want it included in the main result.
- `.*` means match any character that occurs 0 or more times. If you want at least a single character to be between A and B you can use .+ instead.
- `(?=B)` means that B comes after the main expression and that if it matches you don't want it included in the main result.

Edit:

Notepad++ does not support lookahead/behind, so you can replace

```
(A).*(B)
```

with

```
\1\2
```

instead.

Note that this is greedy, so if have "AxB y AzB", you'll get "AB". To get "AB y AB", use

```
(A).*?(B)
```

instead.

*Edited non-greedy, `.?*` was incorrect

Comment: I tried it out and it doesn't match anything. Are you sure its not supposed to be this: [?<=A].*[?=B] in which case it would include A and B in the match.

Comment: My bad -- it's a valid regular expression but it seems Notepad++ doesn't support lookaheads so this won't work in Notepad++. It's not my main editor so I wasn't aware of the missing support.

Answer (score 2):

I'm very new to regular expressions so hopefully this works for you.

I think **A.*B** would be the regular expression to search for. That is, search for A and B with zero or more things between them.

This regular expression includes the A and B in the match so you'd have to add them back in with the replace.

**AreplaceB** Would be the text to replace it with.

[image]

Comment: It's a simple fix though. I think your solution might be better, James answered first so I chose it.